# Regular expression with multiline matching (subtitles strings)

Tags: regex

Need some help in regexp matching pattern.
The text goes like here (it's subtitles for video)

```
...

223
00:20:47,920 --> 00:20:57,520
- Hello! This is good subtitle text. 
- Yes! How are you, stackoverflow?

224
00:20:57,520 --> 00:21:11,120
Wow, seems amazing.
- We're good, thanks. 
Like, you know, everyone is happy around here with their laptops.

225
00:21:11,120 --> 00:21:14,440
- Understood. Some dumb text 

...
```

I need a set of groups:
**startTime**, **endTime**, **text**

For now my achievements are not very good. I can get startTime, endTime and some text, but not all the text, only the last sentence. I've attached a screenshot.

[image]

As you can see, group 3 is capturing text, but only last sentence.

Please, explain me what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that, because of the last `+`, the group 3 is overwritten at every match (therefore you get only the last match). You should use `((?:[^\n]+\n)+)` instead of `([^\n]+\n)+`.

Comment: Please note that `[ ->]` matches all characters from ` ` (space) to and including `>`. I think you want: `[- >]` which matches any of the three characters in the character class.

Comment: @andlrc, classic! I made the same mistake =)

Comment: @horcrux That's it! Now I see what I was missing. Thank's a lot!

Comment: @andlrc understand! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accounting for the possibility there is no new-line character after the final text of your string; Would the following work for you:

```
(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d)[ >-]*?((?1))\n(.*?(?=\n\n|\Z))
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/k6AGmq/13)

---

- `(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d)` - The same pattern as you used to capture starting time in 1st capture group.
- `[ >-]*?` - 0+ (but lazy) character from the character class up to:
- `((?1))` - A 2nd capture group which matches the same pattern as 1st group.
- `\n` - A newline-character.
- `(.*?(?=\n\n|\Z))` - A 3rd capture group that captures anything (including newline with the s-flag) up to a positive lookahead for either two newline characters or the end of the whole string.

---

Note, some (not all) engines allow for backreferencing a previous subpattern. I guess the app you are using does not. Therefor you can swap the (?1) with your own pattern to capture the 2nd group.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Maybe you know, why ((?1)) is not working on different programming languages? It depends on realisation? I try to launch your pattern on iOS app - no way, crashes with error that expression is broken. Although in your demo everything is fine. Also at regexr.com - crashes.

Comment: @PeteStreem, some (not all) engines allow for backreferencing a previous subpattern. I guess the app you are using does not. Therefor you can swap the `(?1)` with your own pattern to capture the 2nd group.

Comment: Ok, roger that. I'm happy that I learned something new today, thanks ;)

Comment: @PeteStreem, but did it work for you in the end?

Comment: No, I configured my pattern in a way like user "horcrux" adviced me and everything is ok. Your realisation is not working on iOS ecosystem devices due to different regexp engine implementation. (Swift language, iOS version 14+). But your solution works on other engines, so in fact you also solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a pattern that would capture all lines in group 3 that do not start with 3 digits.

```
(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d) --> (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d)((?:\r?\n(?!\d\d\d\b).*)*)
```

*Explanation*

- `(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d)` Capture **group 1** Match a time like pattern
- `-->` Match literally
- `(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d)` Capture **group 2** Same pattern as group 1
- `(` Capture **group 3**

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\r?\n(?!\d\d\d\b).*` Match a newline and assert using a negative lookahead that the line does not start with 3 digits followed by word boundary. If that is the case, match the whole line
  - `)*` Optionally repeat all lines
- `)` Close group 3

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N3djlp/1)

A bitmore specific pattern could be matching all lines that do not start with 3 digits or a start/end time like pattern.

```
^(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d)[^\S\r\n]+-->[^\S\r\n]+(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d)((?:\r?\n(?!\d+$|\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d\b).*)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JgxLu7/1)

Comment: Please, see https://regexr.com/5kqph and go to Match 2 in Details panel. You can see, that Group 3 contains a number of the next element. Am I missing something?

Comment: @PeteStreem You can prevent that using `^(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d)[^\S\r\n]+-->[^\S\r\n]+(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d)((?:\r?\n(?!\d+$|\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d\b).*)*)` see https://regexr.com/5kqq0

Comment: @PeteStreem Can you add the pattern that you tried to the question instead of only an image?